Blitzstein, Probability, Chapter2, Problem 25: Blood types, Crime, and Suspects
[The following problem has been dealt with in many pages here on StackExchange. However, no one really has addressed my primary concern. I do not want the solution, I already have it. I just want to understand where I am going wrong, and how do I correct it.]
The problem statement: "A crime is committed by one of two suspects, A and B. Initially, there is equal evidence against both of them. In further investigation at the crime scene, it is found that the guilty party had a blood type found in 10% of the population. Suspect A does match this blood type, whereas the blood type of Suspect B is unknown.
Please consider the solution of the OP to the following problem:
Conditional Probability Summation Rule Problem
(a) Given this new information, what is the probability that A is the guilty party?"
I have followed the same, exact steps of the OP, and have arrived at the same answer of 19/20. The answer to the problem, however, is 10/11.
Although, some people have tried to clarify why 19/20 is NOT the correct answer, I still don't understand the flaw in my or the OP's reasoning.
Please help.

As discussed in the comments on the linked question, there's a bit of sneakiness that means the probability of $B$ having the matching blood type is not 0.1, because it's not independent of the event of $B$ having committed the crime. We can see this via a breakdown of the conditional probabilities as well. Let's call $B$ the event that $B$ committed the crime, and $M$ the event that $B$'s blood type matches that at the crime scene:

If $B$ committed the crime, then we expect their blood to match, i.e. $P(M | B) = 1$.

If $B$ didn't commit the crime, then their blood is as likely to match as any random person off the street, i.e. $P(M | B^c) = \frac{1}{10}$.


So we get $P(M) = P(M | B)P(B) + P(M | B^c)P(B^c) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{9}{20}$.
Additionally, because of this, the events "$B$'s blood matches that at the crime scene" and "$A$'s blood matches that at the crime scene" are also not independent, because if $B$ did commit the crime, there's a 100% chance they'll have the same blood type (because we already know that $A$'s blood type is a match regardless of whether they're the culprit or not).

The assumption that the blood group of B is independent of that of the blood group of A is what is wrong. Imagine that the population consists of 100 people. So 10 people have the blood group of the guilty party (say X). Initially, the chances that B has blood group X are 10%. After you know that A has blood group X, the probability that B has blood group X shall be $\frac{9}{99}$ (B has to be one among the other 9 people with blood group X, and there are 99 people remaining).
